# Query Problem: Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col64

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have been using this formula in a document for quite some time and have had no problems with it. Now however when I opened it up, it suddenly stopped working. When I revert the document to an old version it works again for 10 seconds then stops working. Does anyone know what the issue might be?
This is also the case with another document that had also worked for several months.

Keep in mind that the formula below has worked and I have changed nothing.

Formula:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1oIhJmOEIhk8yfmf-0Q0hD5mF5tROgm-4QRgnuBy5nu0";"Svar!A43:BM");"SELECT * WHERE Col64 is null")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `importrange()` you quote is pointing to a range in the same spreadsheet file where the formula is. You do not need to use `importrange()` but can just reference the range directly, like this:

```
=query(Svar!A43:BM; "where BL is null", 0)
```

If you want to use `ColX` type labels for some reason, put the range reference in an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276):

```
=query({ Svar!A43:BM }; "where Col64 is null", 0)
```